# How do I add delay to every function I trigger at the same time?

Tags: javascript, triggers, scheduled-tasks, telegram-bot, delay

I need to run 3 function at 8AM, so that my telegram bot can send all the messages I need to send, but because of the limitation of the telegram bot (antispam), it sends me this error:

`Exception: Request failed for https://api.telegram.org returned code 429. Truncated server response: {"ok":false,"error_code":429,"description":"Too Many Requests: retry after 36","parameters":{"retry_after":36}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)`

Because of this, someone said that I should add some delay, but I don't know how.

This is my code

```
function function_Triggered() {
  FunctionOne(), FunctionTwo(), FunctionThree()

  deleteTriggers();
  scheduledTrigger(8.00);
}

function scheduledTrigger(hours, minutes){
  var now = new Date();
  var year = now.getFullYear();
  var month = now.getMonth();
  var day = now.getDate();

  pars = [year,month,day,hours,minutes];

  var scheduled_D = new Date(...pars);
  var hours_remain = Math.abs(scheduled_D - now) / 36e5;
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(function_Triggered)
  .timeBased()
  .after(hours_remain * 60 * 60 * 1000)
  .create()
}

function deleteTriggers(){
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i<triggers.length; i++) {
    if(   triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()== function_Triggered) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

can someone help me where and how could I put the delay? I want them to run by itself with 5minutes delay for each functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could either make a trigger for ever function individually or use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

```js
function function_Triggered() {
  setTimeout(FunctionOne, 0);
  setTimeout(FunctionTwo, 1000 * 60 * 5);
  setTimeout(FunctionThree, 1000 * 60 * 5 * 2);

  deleteTriggers();
  scheduledTrigger(8.00);
}
```